# Iterating over PATH with batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I would like to take my %PATH% and add inverted commas to it. In other words, from

```
C:\Program Files\a;C:\Program Files\b;C:\Program Files(x86)\c
```

into

```
"C:\Program Files\a";"C:\Program Files\b";"C:\Program Files(x86)\c"
```

The reason is, of course, those spaces, but that's besides the point. I currently have:

```
@ECHO OFF

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=^; eol=¬" %%G IN ("%PATH%") DO @ECHO "%%G";
```

however, this just gives me the first part of my path:

```
"C:\Program Files\a";
```

which is a step in the right direction, but how do I get it to provide all the rest? Additionally, how would I fold the entire output into a single variable so that I can pass it to another command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "p=%path%"
set "p=%p:"=%"
set p="%p:;=";"%"
echo %p%
```

Comment: Yep, beat me to it.  Or, just `ECHO "%PATH:;=";"%"`.

Comment: @mbroshi Existing quotes need to be removed, which is another line.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
SET "dPath=C:\Program Files\a;C:\Program Files\b;C:\Program Files(x86)\c"
FOR %%a IN ("%dPath:;=";"%") DO ECHO(%%~a
```

---

output:

```
C:\Program Files\a
C:\Program Files\b
C:\Program Files(x86)\c
```

Comment: A path can have quotes in it already and which have to be catered for.

Comment: @foxidrive yes and moreover a `PATH` can have semi-colons :| Thank you for the comment  :)